# In VS Code, how can I keybind toggling between the most recent non-terminal editor and the terminal / a terminal editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

For a long time this has been one of my most used shortcut on VS Code:

```json
{"key": "f1","command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus"},         
{"key": "f1","command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup","when":"terminalFocus"},
```

A simple way to toggle back and forth between the terminal and last active editor. But out of necessity I recently decided to use editor terminals all the time, so much so, they are created by default.

But now I my trusty shortcut only works partially, it will activate a editor terminal but does not activate back to the last active file/editor. I know as far as Code is concerned an editor terminal is a editor so the command does nothing.

So I tried the following, it works if I only have two editor groups open, but If I have more than two open the wrong file is activated:

```
{"key": "f1","command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus"},         
{"key": "f1","command": "workbench.action.focusPreviousGroup","when":"terminalFocus"},
```

If anyone know of any clever means of toggling back and forth between a editor terminal and the last active file/editor I would really love to know!

Comment: what about `Ctrl+\`` (backtick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this in keybindings.json:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
    "when": "editorFocus",
},
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "terminalFocus",
},
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.navigateBack",
    "when": "terminalEditorFocus",
},
```

You might need to add the following to your settings.json:

```json
"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
    "workbench.action.navigateBack",
],
```

Comment: This is perfect, I was certain I would have to go and ask for this feature from the code team, something I dread! Once more, you saved me :D